# Interface as an attribute?

Tags: java

I have a strange class that has a interface object as attribute. What does it mean?

```
public interface Acceptor{
    public void accept(Thing thing);
    public boolean hasSpace();
}

public class Box{
    private final Acceptor acceptor;
    public Box(Acceptor acceptor){
        this.acceptor = acceptor; 
    }
 
    public void acceptor(Thing thing){
         acceptor.accept(thing);
    }
   
    public void hasSpace(){
         return acceptor.hasSpace();
    }
}
```

Say I want to create an instance of Box, how?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does it mean to "program to an interface"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface)

Comment: "I want to create an instance of Box, how?" <- In short, you use the constructor and pass any object that imlements the interface `Acceptor` as a parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means whatever object you pass to the `Box` constructor *must* implement the `Acceptor` interface. To create a `Box` object, you'd need to do something like this:

```
Acceptor a = new Foo(); // assuming Foo implements Acceptor
Box b = new Box(a);
```

Whatever else `Foo` does, as long as it implements the `Acceptor` interface, it will be guaranteed to have everything `Box` needs when it calls `Acceptor` methods on the object passed to the `Box` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You can use anonymous class also:

```java
        Box box=new Box(new Acceptor(){
            @Override
            public void accept(Thing thing) {
                //...
            }

            @Override
            public boolean hasSpace() {
                //...
                return true;
            }          
        });
```

[more about anonymous classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html)